# How to filter out specific words in an Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Okay so, I'm new to Javascript and im just trying to get the hang of loops and how to use them. So I came up with an exercise:

- I will create an Array with random words, some will be fruits.
- I want the loop to go through the Array (I came this far).
- Next I want to filter out only the fruit words, (which are called `mango`, `banana` etc.) and I want to replace these with the word `Fruit`

this is my current code :

```
let words = ['mango','desk','phone','banana','airpods', 6 ,'mouse','strawberry',9,'raspberry', 10];

let wordsArrayLength = words.length;

for (let wordLoop = 0; wordLoop < wordsArrayLength; wordLoop++ ) {

}
```

So I thought I would do a `.filter()` and then call out those names, and replace them with the word `Fruit` but I'm just kinda stuck now and I don't know how to go on from here... I couldnt find anything online that helped me with this, so maybe I didn't really make a good exercise for myself?

Also if anyone has any tips on what to practise with, with Javascript then let me know. Im thinking of making a puzzle/quiz next. I just wanted to know if there was a solution for what im trying to make now or if I just move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array called `fruits` that will have all the fruits item. With that you can loop over to the `words` array and check if the item is fruit or not using `fruits.indexOf()`. If it is simply replace that word with `Fruit`:

```js
let fruits = ['mango','banana','strawberry','raspberry'];
  let words = ['mango','desk','phone','banana','airpods', 6 ,'mouse','strawberry',9,'raspberry', 10];

words.forEach((word, index) => {
  if(fruits.indexOf(word) !== -1){
     words[index] = 'Fruit';
  }
});
console.log(words);
```

Comment: This worked! But i only understand this code until the : fruits.indexOf(word) !== -1 . Why use !== -1? (so sorry, im in the noobie phase)

Comment: @Kiralin if the element exist in the array then the index of that element will be 0 or greater than 0 based on the position they are in. But if they do not exist they have index of `-1` so `fruits.indexOf(word) !== -1` means that the `word` exist in `fruits` array. You can also use `fruits.indexOf(word) >= 0`

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to `filter` out words - you want to create an array that's one-to-one with the original array, only with the fruit words replaced. Use `.map` instead.

You can also put the predefined fruit words into `Set` to reduce runtime complexity:

```js
const fruits = new Set(['mango', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'raspberry']);
const input = ['mango','desk','phone','banana','airpods', 6 ,'mouse','strawberry',9,'raspberry', 10];
const mapped = input.map(val => fruits.has(val) ? 'fruit' : val);
console.log(mapped);
```

Or, using only array methods, you would test to see if the fruits array `includes` the value:

```js
const fruits = ['mango', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'raspberry'];
const input = ['mango','desk','phone','banana','airpods', 6 ,'mouse','strawberry',9,'raspberry', 10];
const mapped = input.map(val => fruits.includes(val) ? 'fruit' : val);
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with map (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

So what the map function does is loop through every item in the array and pass it to a function so you can transform that value